# Error while creating a new file in "Brackets" code editor

Tags: adobe-brackets

I have tried to create a new file in Brackets code editor. It shows up an error message as below.

"Error Creating File: An error occurred when trying to create the file. The target directory cannot be modified.

Comment: Can you please supply more details and describe what exactly did you do?

Comment: In Brackets, 
We have a way to create a new file or folder. So I followed these steps. Right Click on the left panel. We get options to create New file, New folder etc., When I select either New file or New Folder, I see a new file/folder created under screenshots. But When I rename it with any name and click ok, It shows up an error message that it cannot be created.

Comment: Whereas, When I try to create a new file by Going to File menu and then new option, I can create afile under working Files tab on the left panel. But I couldnt create using the options I get when I do with Right click option

Comment: It is better that you add those details to your question so it will be easier for other people to see and help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I figured it out.

Instead of going File->New you have to right click on the folder section in brackets and then select new File which will create a new file in your current folder as well as in the Working Files section.

See image below of where to right click (right click in the red circle):
[image]

I added the file Bootstrap.html to the folder 'Full Stack Dev'